# Programmatically set Default Apps in Windows 10 2H22

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to programmatically set the Default Apps in Windows 10 2H22? Via PowerShell or the like?

I'm searching for a way to set the "Music Player", "Photo Viewer" etc. like in "Settings > Apps > Defaults apps" (see screenshot).

Please do not refer to `ftype`, `assoc`, `dism /online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:` or registry of single file types! This is not what I'm searching for.

Please don't point to closed source solutions like `SetUserFTA`. This question has been posted to actually understand the solution behind, if any.

I need a way to programmatically tell windows "my default app for Music is VLC", "default app for Photos is XNView" etc.

[image]

Comment: So you want an script with parameters, e.g. "setdef -music -vlc" or something like a autoscript which take the first possible app...?

Comment: @Luckylazuli yes. A readable (not closed source) script!

Comment: Because it was 2:40 in the morning. That's why! Sorry.

Comment: There's no official way by design. Microsoft wants the end-user to do it so no one messes up with end-user's associations. So the only way is to simulate end-user actions, ie: use Microsoft UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Comment: As @SimonMourier pointed out, there is no script to make this work automatically that anyone knows, that is why browsers like Chrome cannot set the default browser to themselves. The solution would be force-editing the registry through (silent) elevation.

Comment: @Andrew What do you mean with "force-editing the registry through (silent) elevation"?

Comment: @wolfrevo By that I mean editing the registry entries (I don't remember what HK it was) to set the value to change the default apps, and this is the trick used by Opera if I'm correct. Silent elevation is a technique where applications silence their elevation popups so the user has no choice and the "run as administrator" is automatically done WHEN the UAC is enabled. (don't use it for malware)